# Importing font into css or html?

Tags: html, css, fonts

When I try to import new font from google into the project, it produces different font according to where I import it. Could someone explain

[in HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HXYCW.pngg)

[in CSS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hcjFk.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your importing it wrong in CSS. Use the following:

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster);
```

Comment: Looks like the stylesheet the OP is linking to has already got the @import in it, in which case, all that is needed is link.

Comment: Which link and which line? I don't see it.

Comment: I believe the file that the link element is linking to (Google's Font API) already contains everything needed for the font to work, so linking to the file with the link element is fine.

Answer (score 0):

In your second example (CSS) you've placed the HTML `<link>` element inside your CSS section, which is not allowed (`<link>` may get you CSS, but it, itself, is an HTML element) and therefore why that's not working for you.

Your HTML example works, but even there, the `<link>` element is not in the correct place, you have it in the `<body>` in that example.

**The correct place for a `<link>` element is inside the `<head>` section but NOT inside of a `<style>` element inside the `<head>` section,** like this:

```
 <html>
   <head>
       <link rel="stylesheet" href=". . . ">

       <style>

            h1 {font-family:lobster;}

       </style>


   </head>
   <body>

   </body>
<html>
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS stands for Cascading Style Sheet which simply means you can only give style to your html content  here.

But you can load that font through css also

```
@font-face {
   font-family: lobster;
   src: url(http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/lobster/v16/c28rH3kclCLEuIsGhOg7evY6323mHUZFJMgTvxaG2iE.woff2);
}
```

and in your css id or class wherever you want this font just type `font-family: "lobster"` and it will work same as if your include this link in html